# Python: Extract values after decimal using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am given a string which is number example "44.87" or "44.8796". I want to extract everything after decimal (.). I tried to use regex in Python code but was not successful. I am new to Python 3.

```
import re

s = "44.123"
re.findall(".","44.86")
```

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried; maybe we can help with why it didn’t work.

Comment: Try `’\.(\d+)$’` as the regex pattern, rather than `’.’`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like `s.split('.')[1]` should work

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use regex try:

```
import re

s = "44.123"
regex_pattern = "(?<=\.).*"
matched_string = re.findall(regex_pattern, s)
```

`?<=` a negative look behind that returns everything after specified character

`\.` is an escaped period

`.*` means "match all items after the period

This [online regex tool](https://regex101.com/) is a helpful way to test your regex as you build it. You can confirm this solution there! :)

Comment: What if the string contains a letter or special character?  ... it is just a string after all.

Comment: This method would still work. Essentially it's searching from left to right to identify the first period and returning everything after.